# Determinant of matrix with power series terms

Tags: power-series, exponential-function, matrix-equations, exponential-sum

I'm trying to find an alternative to the Taylor series which represents some function $f(x)$ as a sum of exponentials.

$$f(x) = a_0 e^{0x} + a_1 e^{1x} + a_2 e^{2x} + a_3 e^{3x} + ...$$

The coefficients $a_0, a_1, a_2...$ can be found by equating the derivatives:
$$a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... = f(0)$$
$$0 + a_1 + 2a_2 + 3a_3 + ... = f'(0)$$
$$0 + a_1 + 4a_2 + 9a_3 + ... = f''(0)$$

In general you can write out $n$ equations to solve for $n$ coefficients. You can solve for the coefficients by solving the following matrix equation $[M] a = f$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & .. & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & .. & (n-1)^{n-4}\\ 
0 & 1 & 4 & 9 & .. & (n-1)^{n-3}\\ 
0 & ..  & .. & .. & .. & (n-1)^{n-2}\\ 
0 & 1 & (n-4)^{n-1} & (n-3)^{n-1} & (n-2)^{n-1} & (n-1)^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
a_0\\ 
a_1\\ 
a_2\\ 
..\\ 
a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
f(0)\\ 
f'(0)\\ 
f''(0)\\ 
..\\ 
f^{(n-1)}(0)
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now to find all coefficients I need to solve $[M]^{-1}f$ as $n$ approaches infinity. But how can I find and simplify the inverse of this matrix? Can someone help me find the closed analytical expression for the i'th coefficient $a_i$?

Comment: Instead of looking at the behavior of $f$ at $0$, would you be OK looking at the behavior at $-\infty$? If so, then notice that $g(u)=f(\ln u)$ is a power series, and that $a_n=\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.

Comment: Write $X=e^x$, then you are simply computing $f(x)=f(\log X)=g(X)=a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+\dots$. How is it different than a polynomial? Accordingly, you find a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). That is, the same matrix found when doing polynomial  interpolation. Just apply one of the many ways to compute the interpolating polynomial (with the same problems with numerical stability if you want the coefficients).

Comment: Thanks! However, this means that if I take this series about $x=0$ then I will get the first coefficient $a_0 = f(-\infty)$. @StefanLafon I could try $f(x) = a_0 e^{(x-c)^0} + a_1 e^{(x-c)^1} + a_2 e^{(x-c)^2} + ...$. However, I would somehow need to make $c=-ln(0) = +\infty$. But this seems messy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $u=e^x$ then $(f\circ\ln)(u)=f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{nx}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nu^n$.  Hence, provided $f\circ\ln$ has a $C^\infty$ extension $g$ to a neighborhood of zero,
$$a_n=\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}.$$
For the case where $g$ has no such extension, you will have to do more work.  I would delete this answer if I could, but you will have to un-accept it first.

Comment: I agree, thanks! Doesn't this mean that $a_0 = f(-\infty)$? If so, doesn't this mean that this exponential sum can only converge assuming that $f(-\infty) = constant$?

Comment: @MatthewJames That's a good point, and so my original answer is incorrect.  I edited it accordingly.